# Coil Image Loader : Cache Bitmap with a key

Tags: java, android, kotlin, coil

I am using [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/) Image loading library.

**My Problem:**

**I am not getting image Url** from backend, rather I am getting **JPEG encoded String with its name / key.**

What I was wondering is if there is any **inbuilt support for caching** `bitmap` with **respect to a key** so that I can avoid asking for that encoded string every time I want to show that Image.

Is it possible? If not what might be the best way to solve my issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coil relies on [OkHttp's disk cache](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-cache/) which controls its own cache key which is based off the URL. However it's possible to set the memory cache key using [RequestBuilder.key](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/api/coil-base/coil.request/-request-builder/key/).

If you need to set the cache key for the data after it's been fetched, I don't think there's an inbuilt solution for that at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: From Coil docs: Coil 1.x relied on OkHttp's disk cache. Coil 2.x has its own disk cache and should not use OkHttp's Cache.